# Points on unit circle with arguments from an arithmetic progression

Tags: complex-numbers, arithmetic-progressions

I'm having trouble understanding a small detail from a paper I'm reading about Roth's theorem. Below is the context.

Let $A \subset \mathbb{Z}_{N}$ be such that $\left|\sum_{x \in A}{\exp\left(\frac{2\pi i rx}{N}\right)} \right| \geq 3 \gamma N$ for some $r \neq 0$, and $\gamma$ is such that $1/\gamma$ is a positive integer $n$. Assume that $N$ is a large prime number (in particular so that $r$ and $N$ are coprime).

Now, divide the unit circle in the complex in $n$ equal parts and let $P_{k} = \left\{x \in \mathbb{Z}_{N}: \exp\left(\frac{2\pi i rx}{N}\right) \in I_{k}\right\}$, where $r \neq 0$, and $k$ is a fixed number $k \in \left\{1,\ldots,n\right\}$. Why does it follow that $P_{k}$ is an arithmetic progression (with difference $r^{-1}$, the inverse of $r$ in $\mathbb{Z}_{N}$)?

Thanks!

Comment: What's $I_k$ ??

Comment: Very unclear what you are asking. Is $I_k = \exp \left( 2 \pi {\rm i} \left[ \frac {k-1} n, \frac k n \right] \right)$? Or are these $I_k$ completely arbitrary, only of equal measure?